# How did Mr. Poopy-Butthole meet the Smiths?

Tags: rick-and-morty

[image]

Mr. Poopy-Butthole is a long time family friend of the Smith's in Rick and Morty. Has there been any explanation of how he met them?

Comment: I object to calling them Smiths.  We all know they are really the Sanchez family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unknown.

According to [his Wikia page](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Poopybutthole):

> Mr. Poopybutthole is a long-time family friend of the Smiths. Rick clearly considers him to have long been a dependable person, although it's uncertain how long they've known each other. [...] Mr. Poopybutthole is a very good friend to the Smiths, and although his exact relation to them is unknown, he is described as a long-time friend of the family.

There is a [theory](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/3ih2ix/rick_morty_so_what_was_the_backstory_behind_mr/) that he never really existed, or was never a close friend of the family, and just a false memory implanted by the parasitic aliens. But this theory has been debunked in [an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oCqPDngrgM&feature=youtu.be&t=1h48m25s) with Rick and Morty co-creator Justin Roiland, who confirmed that Mr Poopybutthole was real.

Comment: Mr. Poopybutthole is *real* though, he got shot and didn't turn into a parasite. And then he wen't through rehab therapy to learn to walk again, and well... now I'm just sad for him :(

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Yes, he's definitely real. I just mentioned that theory and its debunking in case you (or anyone else reading) might be a proponent of it :-)

Comment: *Rick and Morty* is a story set in multiverse. *Mr. Poopybutthole* is real, but nobody ever told that he's from the dimension **C-137**. Therefore most probable theory is that S02E04 happened in some alternate universe.

Comment: That theory you linked has this comment: "Mr. Poopybutthole's origin episode, it's one of the S1 BluRay Easter Eggs."  Am I correct in assuming that person was a troll?

Comment: @oski86 I believe they confirmed that multiple episodes in season 2 did not follow our normal Rick and Morty pair.